# How to Split Dataframe by Deliminator

Tags: r, dataframe, split, delimiter

I am using `readbulk::read_bulk()` to load several (~40+) .dat files into R. I was able to successfully load in another set of .dat files that used `,` as delimiters, but I was unable to do it for a set of files that used `|` as delimiters. How can I load these files and separate the data into columns given the `|` delimiter? Or, how can I separate the loaded data.frame by the `|` delimiter?

Example:

```
TEMP <- read_bulk(directory = "C:/Users/ABC/Desktop/Dat Files")
```

This produces a `TEMP` file with 19799 obs of 3 variables. As such, it is not separating them out by the `|` delimiter.

I've also tried:

```
files <- list.files(path = "C:/Users/ABC/Desktop/Dat Files2", pattern = "*.dat")

TEMP <- read_bulk(directory = "C:/Users/ABC/Desktop/Dat Files2", fun = utils::read.csv(file = files, sep = "\\|"))
```

But I get:

```
Error in file(file, "rt") : invalid 'description' argument
```

Comment: Looking at `?read_bulk` I see that you can specify a reader function, which will take further arguments through `...`, by default its `read.csv()`. Take a look at `?read.csv` and see if it will take a seperator argument.

Comment: I tried that, however, the issue is the `read.csv` is file specific, and I have 48 files I need to load into a single dataframe.

Comment: And some use `,` as delimiter, while others use `|`?

Comment: That's not really a reproducible example. We need the contents of a few of those .dat files. A representative subset, small enough to reproduce the error, but not so big it will fill up a computer screen.

Comment: Unless we have access to your C drive, showing the code that you use for reading files doesn't make it reproducible. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)